# When does XML receive it's value to display?

Tags: xml, odata, sapui5

I am trying to figure out when XML retrieves it's value to display in SAP UI5. It is bound to an OData Model, so I assume it must perform a `read()` to figure out what value to display. Therefore I would be able to use this information in my controller after the XML performs the `read()`.

example.xml

```
<ComboBox items="{
                    path: '/ZSpace_EntitySet',
                    sorter: { path: 'Name' }
                 }">
    <core:Item key="{Value}" text="{Name}" />
</ComboBox>
```

so in debugging mode I tried doing `this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/ZSpace_EntitySet(...)/propertyHere")` but it returns undefined. I have tried it for both `onBeforeShow()` and `onAfterShow()`. I paused the debugger on these methods and performed the line above.

I'm thinking that I need a function that runs right after the XML gets its values to display because it will have performed the `read()` to populate the XML.

Update: By the time `onBeforeHide()` is run, the model is, of course, present and I can perform the line above. But this is way too late, I would like to read the property before this.

Comment: "when XML retrieves it's value". XML does not do anything. XML is the specification of a data format. Whatever it is that retrieves the value, it's not XML. Finding out what retrieves the value might help you discover when it does so.

Comment: Yes of course but I was just trying to get the idea as @StephenS did, thanks though, I edited the title to add your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a [dataReceived](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Binding.html#event:dataReceived) handler on the ComboBox binding. This handler is triggered when the data request for the control is complete.

XML Code

```
<ComboBox id="cmbBox" items="{
                path: '/ZSpace_EntitySet',
                sorter: { path: 'Name' }
             }">
<core:Item key="{Value}" text="{Name}" />
```

Controller code

```
onBeforeRendering : function(){
        var oComboBox = this.byId("cmbBox"),
            oBinding = oComboBox.getBinding("items");
        oBinding.attachDataReceived(function(){
            window.alert("Data Received");
        });
}
```

Comment: How did I forgot about this, I will check and let you know

Comment: Looks good, would you happen to know if this can be done with simple bindings like if I just did `value={field}`? Using your method makes the oBinding undefined which makes me think I have to use another method for this type of binding.

Comment: I tried with the XML binding but it didn't work. Unfortunately the documentation also does not mention any way of doing it.